# Поиск объекта в массиве

Tags: php, json

Есть вот такой JSON файл:

```
{
  "terminals": [
    {
      "token": "hile_abcd1234",
      "name": "Hile Group Authorized Agent",
      "scopes": [
        "r"
      ]
    },
    {
      "token": "hile_absd1234",
      "name": "Hile Group Authorized Agent 2",
      "scopes": [
        "w"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Как найти токен `hile_absd1234` и вернуть массив в котором он находится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = json_decode($string, true);

$res = array_filter($arr['terminals'], 
            function($x) { return $x['token'] == 'hile_absd1234'; });
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/925545)

Comment: Еще один вопрос, как мне получить массив `scopes`. Вот что мне выводит Ваш код: `Array ( [1] => Array ( [token] => hile_absd1234 [name] => Hile Group Authorized Agent 2 [scopes] => Array ( [0] => w ) ) ) `

Comment: возможно имеет смысл добавить `array_pop`

Comment: @teran А зачем?

Comment: @splash58 не правда, `$res[1]['scopes']`, поэтому и написал, что pop не помешает.

Comment: @Teran да, точно, не доглядел. Возможно, даже цикл надо, если нет уверенности, что в результат только один элемент

Comment: @teran Соглашусь, попробовал, сработало! splash58 тебе тоже спасибо!

Comment: @IvanSteklow индекс `[1]`  зависит от исходных данных, это именно индекс элемента в исходном массиве. то есть он будет разным, в зависимости от данных, и так его использовать нельзя.

Comment: @teran А как мне только один (самый первый элемент) найти?

Comment: @IvanSteklow так `$res = array_shift($res)`

Comment: @IvanSteklow w так - `echo array_shift($res)['scopes'][0];`

Comment: @teran Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

да вроде ничего сложного?

```
$json = '{"terminals":[{"token":"hile_abcd1234","name":"Hile Group Authorized Agent","scopes":["r"]},{"token":"hile_absd1234","name":"Hile Group Authorized Agent 2","scopes":["w"]}]}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$result = null;
$needle = "hile_absd1234";

foreach($data['terminals'] as $t){
    if($t['token'] === $needle){
        $result = $t;
        break;
    }    
}
print_r($result);
```

как уже описано у @splash58, можно использовать `array_filter`, однако тут в результате будет массив, внутри которого - искомый результат. Альтернативой может стать `array_reduce`

```
$result = array_reduce($data['terminals'], function($carry, $item) use ($needle){
             if($item['token'] === $needle){
                $carry = $item;
             }
             return $carry;
          });

print_r($result);
```

он вернет сразу искомый массив.

недостатком обоих функций массивов в том, что они просмотрят весь массив полностью, в то время как в цикле мы можем сделать `break` после нахождения элемента.

Comment: **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** выдает, когда проверяю, содержимое файла выводит, а преобразование json в объект - выводит пустой массив

Comment: @IvanSteklow как, откуда и в каком виде файл читаете?

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию:

```
$need = 'hile_absd1234';
$result = [];
$array = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if ($v['token'] == $need) {
            $result[] = $arr[$k];
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($result, true), '</pre>';
```